# React Native: Can you place an item in front of another, but still have the item behind be clickable?

Tags: css, react-native, touchableopacity

In my React Native app, I have a parent element that contains two child elements, a `<Text>` and a `<TouchableOpacity>`. I want the `<Text>` to be in front of the `<TouchableOpacity>`, but have the `<TouchableOpacity>` be clicked when the user taps the visible element. The actual scenario is more complicated than this, so I'm not looking for obvious alternatives like putting the `<TouchableOpacity>` in front of the `<Text>`. I just want to know if this is possible.

```
<View>
  <TouchableOpacity/>
  <Text style={{position: 'absolute'}}>hello<Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can place a layout on top of another and can control whether the layout behind can be the target of touch events with the Prop `pointerEvents`

Here is an example with your code snippet:

```
<View>
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={onPressHandler}
    style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: 50, width: '100%'}}
  />
  <View
    pointerEvents="none" // The Text View is never the target of touch events.
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '100%',
      height: 40,
    }}>
    <Text>hello</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

For more details on `pointerEvents`: [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#pointerevents)